# Gamma Distribution Sum

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to show that the sum of three independent gamma distributions $X_1\sim \Gamma(2,5)$, $X_2\sim \Gamma(3,5)$, and $X_3\sim\Gamma(1.5,2.5)$ are a gamma distribution. $Y=X_1+X_2+2X_3$. I've multiplied the moment generating functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and I've squared the moment generating function of $X_3$ and am left with gamma distributions that I cannot multiply together to give me another Gamma distribution. How would I proceed?

$\frac{1}{2.5^3\left(\frac{1}{2.5}-t\right)^3}\left(\frac{1}{5^5\left(\frac{1}{5}-t\right)^5}\right)$

Comment: Hint: Assuming you're using shape/scale Gamma and not shape/rate, we have $2 X_3 \sim \Gamma(1.5, 2 \cdot 2.5) = \Gamma(1.5,5)$.

Comment: It's of the form Γ($\alpha,\beta$). As my expression above shows, the denominator includes $\beta^\alpha$. How can I multiply the beta value like you say?

Comment: pay attention only to those components attached to $x_3$.  $f(2x_3) \propto (2x_3)^{\alpha}e^{-\beta2x_3}\times 2 \propto x_3^{\alpha}e^{-2\beta x_3} \propto \Gamma(\alpha, 2\beta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming shape/scale not shape/rate (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution - I can tell by the mgf you're using).

Then $2X_3 \sim \Gamma(1.5,5)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Scaling - it might be good to prove this for yourself). Let $Z = X_1+X_2+2X_3$, then by independence the mgf of $Z$ is the product of the mgf of $X_1, X_2,$ and $2X_3$:
$$
M_Z(t) = \left[ \left( 1 - 5t  \right)^{-2} \right]
\left[ \left( 1 - 5t \right)^{-3} \right]
\left[ \left( 1 - 5t\right)^{-1.5} \right] \text{ for } t< 1/5
$$
which simplifies to $M_Z(t) = (1-5t)^{-6.5}$ for $t<1/5$. We recognize this as the mgf of a $\Gamma(6.5,5)$ random variable.

Comment: Could you direct me to where in the article it's discussed that 2X3∼Γ(1.5,5)? I'm having difficulty understanding why it wouldn't be Γ(3,2.5).

Comment: Also, it might be useful to note that I'm using the formula where Γ($\alpha, \beta$) and $M(t)=\frac{1}{\beta^\alpha(\frac{1}{\beta}-t)^\alpha})$.

Comment: Woops i meant to link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Scaling. That's the same MGF as the one in wiki. . . $(1- \beta t)^{-\alpha}$. If $X \sim \Gamma(1.5, 2.5)$, then $M_{2X}(t) = E[e^{2Xt}] = M_X(2t) = (1- 2 \cdot 2.5t)^{-1.5} = (1-5 t)^{-1.5}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y_1 \sim Gamma(shape = \alpha_1, rate=\lambda)$ and 
$Y_2 \sim Gamma(shape = \alpha_2, rate=\lambda)$, then
$Y_1 + Y_2 \sim Gamma(shape = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2, rate=\lambda),$
as can be seen by multiplying moment generating functions. Notice that the shape parameters add, and the rate parameters are the *same.*

Of course, it is possible to find the CDF and PDF of the sum of the three
distributions you mention, but ***I do not believe that sum has a gamma
distribution.*** It is easy to find the expectation $\mu_Y$ and the variance $\sigma^2_Y$ of the sum your three gammas, but I do not believe
those match the mean and variance of any gamma distribution.

Below is a histogram of a million simulated realizations of the sum $W$ of $Y_1 \sim Gamma(2, 1)$ and
$Y_2 \sim Gamma(3, 2)$ along with R's default density estimator of the sum. 
I have also found the approximate mean and SD of the sum. The mean
of a gamma distribution is $\mu = \alpha/\lambda$ and the variance is
$\sigma^2 = \alpha/\lambda^2.$ I believe you can show there is no
choice of parameters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ that match these formulas, and also
the mean and variance of $W.$ Hence, $W$ cannot be gamma.

```
 m = 10^6;  y1 = rgamma(m, 2, 1);  y2 = rgamma(m, 3, 2)
 w = y1 + y2;  mean(w);  sd(w);  sqrt(2 + 3/4)
 ## 3.498231  # aprx E(W) = 3.5
 ## 1.655406  # aprx SD(W)
 ## 1.658312  # exact SD(W)
 hist(w, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Estimated Density of Sum of 2 Gammas with Different Rates")
   lines(density(w), lwd=2, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]

Comment: What distribution would it be then?

Comment: Not all distributions have names. As far as I know, this one doesn't. (But they do all have CDFs. "By their CDFs shall ye know them.")